# loginWithPopup() does not work with auth0 spa

Tags: reactjs, auth0

[image]

I am creating an auth0 spa login page with loginWithPopup(), but every time it responds with a misconfiguration error but the same works with loginWithRedirect() without any problem. Just like loginWithRedirect(), I want a username and password fields (in loginWithPopup()) where I can enter my credentials and redirect to the home page. Please look at the image for the error page.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useAuth0 } from "../react_auth0";


const Login = props => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const { isAuthenticated, loginWithRedirect, loginWithPopup, logout } = useAuth0();
    const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

    const logoutWithRedirect = () =>
        logout({
            returnTo: window.location.history
        });

    const login = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        await loginWithPopup({});
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={login}>
                Login
      </button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

My react-auth0-spa.js code is exactly as auth0 spa sample code as in their Github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of struggle, I found answer to my own question. In order to use loginWithPopup() from auth0 SDK, we must include our callback URL in the allowed web origin field as well (which I was not doing before). loginWithPopup() is a combination of PKCE + web_message. https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2 (under how response mode works?) https://auth0.com/blog/introducing-auth0-single-page-apps-spa-js-sdk (under behind the curtain)